# Nginx running but not serving index.html

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, nginx-config, npm-build

I'm trying to serve some html content that I built using npm build. The html and other static files are ready to be served and present inside the `/var/www/build directory`.

When I do `nginx -t` with sudo privileges, I'm getting the follwoig output:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Can someone explain if there's something wrong with my conf file. A little help would be appreciated. Thanks

Below I'm writing my nginx.conf file content.

nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  domain.com;
        root         /var/www/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       80 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  domain.com;
#        root         /var/www/build;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

The content inside /var/www/build folder:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  605 Apr 24 21:14 asset-manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3870 Apr 24 21:14 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  644 Apr 24 21:14 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5347 Apr 24 21:14 logo192.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9664 Apr 24 21:14 logo512.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  492 Apr 24 21:14 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67 Apr 24 21:14 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   40 Apr 24 21:14 static
```